# VB.NET JSON Object Issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, json, jayrock

**UPDATE:** So I've figured it out! All I had to do was use `jQuery.parseJSON();` and it converted the JSON string into a JSON Object. Here is the updated code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "GetEEs.aspx/GetNextEEs",
  data: "{recordID:" + lastItem + "}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (msg, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var jObject = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
    ddl.length = 0;
    $.each(jObject.d, function () {
      $.each(this, function (index, item) {
        addItemToDDL(ddl, item.Display, item.Value);
      });
    });
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
});
```

Ok, I've written a function to query a table and return a dataset, then convert it to JSON so the page can use it. The function is below:

```
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function GetNextEEs(ByVal recordID As Integer) As ArrayList
        If Not recordID.Equals(0) Then
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT TOP 500 * FROM cbotest WHERE ID > " & recordID
            Dim arr As New ArrayList

            Using dr As SqlDataReader = Mangrove.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader("...")
                While dr.Read()
                    arr.Add(New ArrayList() From { _
                     New With { _
                      Key .Value = dr("code").ToString, _
                      Key .Display = dr("description").ToString _
                     }
                    })
                End While
            End Using

            Return arr
        Else
            Throw New ApplicationException("Invalid Record ID")
        End If
    End Function
```

The function works great in .Net 4, but I can't use it with .Net 2. So I found a JSON.Net Object called [Jayrock](http://jayrock.berlios.de/). I changed my function to use it and everything works. Here is the revised function:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetNextEEs(ByVal recordID As Integer) As String
    If Not recordID.Equals(0) Then
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT TOP 500 * FROM cbotest WHERE ID > " & recordID
        Dim json As JsonObject = New JsonObject()
        Dim items As JsonArray = New JsonArray()

        Using dr As SqlDataReader = Mangrove.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader("...")
            While dr.Read()
                Dim item As JsonArray = New JsonArray()
                Dim itemArr As JsonObject = New JsonObject()

                itemArr.Add("Value", dr("code").ToString)
                itemArr.Add("Display", dr("description").ToString)

                item.Add(itemArr)
                items.Add(item)
            End While
        End Using

        json.Add("d", items)

        Using writer As JsonWriter = New EmptyJsonWriter()
            json.Export(writer)
            Return json.ToString
        End Using
    Else
        Throw New ApplicationException("Invalid Record ID")
    End If
End Function
```

The only problem is when it returns the JSON, the page can't parse it.

Here is an example of the outputs from both functions:

First Version:
`[object Object],[object Object],[object Object], ...`

Revised Version:
`{"d":[[{"Value":"501","Display":"Record Number 501"}],[{"Value":"502","Display":"Record Number 502"}], ...`

As you can see, the revised version returns an actual string (That contains the correct data) where as the first version returned a JSON Object. I know it's because of the function returning as a `String`, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to return a JSON Object using the revised code.

Does anybody have an idea on how to do this, or a better solution? I'm stumped! Also, please remember that this is for .Net 2 (sucks, I know :/)

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT**
Here is some of the client side code that I'm using:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "GetEEs.aspx/GetNextEEs",
  data: "{recordID:" + lastItem + "}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (msg, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //alert(msg.d);
    document.getElementById('lbl').innerHTML = msg.d;
    ddl.length = 0;
    $.each(msg.d, function () {
      $.each(this, function (index, item) {
        addItemToDDL(ddl, item.Display, item.Value);
      });
    });
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
});
```

I had an `alert(item);` inside of the inner-most loop. It was going letter by letter through the string.

Comment: Can we see some client-side code?

Comment: Added the client code, but that shouldn't change nor need to change, correct? It was working before, and the only thing I changed was the `GetNextEEs` function.

Comment: I think `WebMethod` adds the `d` attribute to the response automatically. But Jayrock also adds the `d` attribute to the JSON. So Jayrock does not play nice with `WebMethod`. I guess you should do `$.each(msg.d.d, function () { ... }` on the client side.

Comment: I just tried that, unfortunately it displays `undefined` :/ Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I've figured it out! I created a new var and used `jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);` and it converted the JSON string to a JSON object. Yes! Whoo! Haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "GetEEs.aspx/GetNextEEs",
  data: "{recordID:" + lastItem + "}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (msg, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var jObject = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
    ddl.length = 0;
    $.each(jObject.d, function () {
      $.each(this, function (index, item) {
        addItemToDDL(ddl, item.Display, item.Value);
      });
    });
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
});
```